# How to delete an element from a Firestore aray?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm want to sub or unsub user to an event store in Firebase. I succeed to put new entrees but not delete.

Here what's my database looks like:

```
event => - name : party in Paris
         - date : 03/08/2019
         - description : awsome Party
         - registered
           [0]
             {
               userId : wxgqF324FDVsgsdf
               userName : toto
             }
           [1]
             {
               userId : dfhdghjyxfgjhx456jH
               userName : tata
             }
```

When I want to delete user in [0] let's say, I cannot succeed to reach it and delete from this map

```
unSubToEvent(eventId, userId) {
    return Firestore.collection('events')
      .doc(eventId)
      .update({
        registered: Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(userId)
      })
 }
```

I would like to have

```
event => - name : party in Paris
         - date : 03/08/2019
         - description : awsome Party
         - registered
           [0]
             {
               userId : dfhdghjyxfgjhx456jH
               userName : tata
             }
```

Comment: Sorry for my english it's not my language so if it's not clear enough i'm sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this.

I wasn't passing the right arguments. I only passed `userId`, but you need to pass the couple ( userId + userName ). Now it works for me!

```
unSubToEvent(eventId, user) {
    return Firestore.collection('events')
      .doc(eventId)
      .update({
        registered: Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(user)
      })
 }
```

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution Nicolas. You indeed need to pass in the complete item to remove it (or to check for existence with `array-contains`).